# Tridion 2011 GUI Extensions: What is the proper usage of the pagetype element in the configuration?

Tags: gui-extensions, configuration, extension-model

One of the requirements for a Tridion GUI Extension which I'm building is that there needs to be a 'configurations' page, where Tridion users can provide certain settings. I am trying to create a button in the Ribbon that, when clicked, takes the user to a page.

Right now, Tridion itself (when I try to load it) is telling me, **"could not load type [Extension].Controls.PageName"**.

I have a strong suspicion that it's because I don't understand the proper usage of *pagetype* element. Could someone explain what values I should give to this element?

```
<ext:extension pageid="ToolsPage" name="Crocodoc" assignid="crocodoc" insertbefore="MaintenanceGroup">
       <ext:control>~/Controls/CrocodocSettings.ascx</ext:control>
       <ext:pagetype>Crocodoc.SettingsPage</ext:pagetype>
       <ext:dependencies>
          <cfg:dependency>Crocodoc.Resources.Settings</cfg:dependency>
       </ext:dependencies>
       <ext:apply>
         <ext:view name="DashboardView">
            <ext:control id="DashboardToolbar" />
      </ext:view>
   </ext:apply>
</ext:extension>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### ext:pagetype

It is used for specifying the javascript implementation.

### Update:

Your issue could be due to not registering the page type.

Example:

```
XXX.registerPageType(YYYYY, "Crocodoc.SettingsPage");
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, but unfortunately that doesn't help me. If I remove this line from my configuration file, then Tridion shows me, `The element 'extension' in namespace 'http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions' has invalid child element 'dependencies' in namespace 'http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions'. List of possible elements expected: 'pagetype' in namespace`. So apparently, it's needed... so could you explain what JavaScript I should be specifying?

Comment: @paceaux: Why you are removing the element? pagetype needs to be specified

Comment: I understand that now. What JavaScript should I specify, then?

Comment: @paceaux: can you show your JS file?

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't realized that it was necessary to have a javascript object set up. I'd completely missed that I needed a javascript file, but once I added one, I understand now where the pageType comes into play